# mysql query group by name

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a MySQL query.

I have this table:

```
Name  | Date       | City
------+------------+------
Peter | 2013-04-01 | Berlin
Paul  | 2013-03-01 | London
Peter | 2013-03-01 | New York 
Peter | 2013-01-28 | Tokio
```

I need, for each name, the first date and corresponding city in the table.

I tried:

```
SELECT Name, MIN(Date) as MD, MIN(City) as CN FROM table GROUP BY Name
```

But the dates don't corresponds to the city name, the result was:

```
Peter, 2013-01-028, Berlin
```

Can anybody give me a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a subquery to get the `min(date)` by `name` and then join that result to your table on both the `name` and `date`:

```
SELECT t1.Name, 
  t1.Date as MD, 
  t1.City as CN 
FROM yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select min(date) MinDate, name
  from yourtable
  group by name
) t2
  on t1.name = t2.name
  and t1.date = t2.mindate
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c7bb/2)

The result is:

```
|  NAME |                             MD |     CN |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Paul |   March, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 | London |
| Peter | January, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  Tokio |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT Name, MIN(Date) as MD, City as CN FROM table GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Will return the lowest date and a random city (not necessarily the city associated with the lowest date)

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` should give the result you want without making the query too complex;

```
SELECT m1.* FROM myTable m1
LEFT JOIN myTable m2
  ON m1.Name = m2.Name
 AND m1.`date` > m2.`date`
WHERE m2.Name is NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0407/2).

It will basically select all rows where there's no older row with the same name.

```
NAME    DATE          CITY
Paul    2013-03-01    London
Peter   2013-01-28    Tokio
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it.

```
SELECT
  m.Name,
  m.Date,
  m.City
FROM mytable as m
INNER JOIN (select min(date) as LDate, name from mytable group by name) as l
    on l.LDate = m.date
      and l.name = m.name
group by m.name
```

### Demo

Output

```
Name  | Date        | City
-----------------------------
Paul  | 2013-03-01  | London
Peter | 2013-01-28  | Tokio
```

Comment: The city associated with Peter/2013-01-28 is supposed to be Tokio.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IN clause:

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  (Name, Date) IN (SELECT Name, Min(Date)
                        FROM yourtable
                        GROUP BY Name)
```

Subquery will return, for each Name, the Name and it's minimum date. The outer query returns all rows where the name and the date corresponds to the ones returned by the subquery.